# php ftp_raw 'quote lzdc on' not working as expected

Tags: php, ftp

The FTP server I am using supports a feature that allows downloaded files to be hidden once downloaded using quote lzdc on.

In the code below should make file 445387.oin NOT show up as it has already been downloaded. But when I list the directory it shows up.

```
if(ftp_login($ftp_conn, 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'))
{
    ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true);

    //This should make file hidden that has been downloaded
    ftp_raw($ftp_conn, "quote lzdc on");

    $files = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn,'INVOICES');
    var_dump($files);
}

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "00_index.txt"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "00_index.htm"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "445387.oin"
}
```

The file 445387.oin has been downloaded so it should NOT show up in list.

RAW FTP Session showing how it should work:

```
ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (74,254,143,170,209,145)
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for directory listing.
-r--r--r--  1 owner group       1024 Dec  8 14:18 00_index.txt
-r--r--r--  1 owner group       1024 Dec  8 14:18 00_index.htm
-r--r--r--  1 owner group       5002 Dec  8 11:03 445387.oin
226 Transfer complete.
ftp> quote lzdc on
230 Limit Zero Download Count - Enabled
ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (74,254,143,170,209,146)
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for directory listing.
-r--r--r--  1 owner group       1024 Dec  8 14:18 00_index.txt
-r--r--r--  1 owner group       1024 Dec  8 14:18 00_index.htm
226 Transfer complete.
```

Is there a way to do this in php?

Comment: `quote` is something for the local ftp client, saying basically "anything after quote is to be sent to the remote server as-is". not sure that the php stuff qualifies as a "client" that needs to be told that... start checking return values, e.g. see if your ftp_raw returned a boolean false on that particular call. maybe the call should be just "lzdc on", without any quoting.

Comment: @MarcB removing quote fixed the issue. If you would like to post as answer this might help someone else.

Comment: t'was just a guess, so... not going to claim it as an answer.